# Easyb with Data-driven Development?

Tags: maven, bdd, maven-plugin, easyb

in the latest version of easyb (0.9.8.2) it seems to be possible to have "where" and "example" statements to make a Data-driven testing possible.

In my POM, I'm using the latest version of the easyb plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.easyb</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-easyb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                  <storyreport>${project.build.directory}/easyb/easyb-stories.txt</storyreport>
                  <xmlreport>${project.build.directory}/easyb/report.xml</xmlreport>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

but I can't get the "where"/"example" statement working. I tried to add a dependency such as

```
         <dependency>
           <groupId>org.easyb</groupId>
           <artifactId>easyb</artifactId>
           <version>0.9.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

but still nothing, is there anything I am missing?

Cheers,
Sebastiano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works using that dependency, I guess we can close the question.